# LongListSelector.ItemTemplate Binding with IValueConverter receives parent viewmodel object instead of individual ItemsSource objects

Tags: windows-phone-8, itemtemplate, ivalueconverter, longlistselector

For some reason, my LongListSelector is passing its inherited DataContext into my ItemTemplate converter causing the list items to display their default `.ToString()` value instead of my template.

I initially had the ItemTemplate defined as a Button control with a Template bound to a property of the items bound to the LongListSelector and that used an IValueConverter to grab the proper ControlTemplate:

ParentViewModel.cs

```
...
List<ChildViewModel> ChildViewModels { get; set; }
...
```

ChildViewModel.cs

```
...
MyEnumType MyEnumType { get; set; }
...
```

MainPage.xaml

```
<phone:LongListSelector x:Name="MyLongListSelector"
                        IsGroupingEnabled="False"
                        ItemsSource="{Binding ChildViewModels}">
    <phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Button Template="{Binding MyEnumType, Converter={StaticResource MyConverter}}" DataContext="{Binding}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
</phone:LongListSelector>
```

This worked fine, but I'm pretty sure I don't need to define a Button as the data template since I should be able to capture anything I need based on the selection event of the LLS.

So, trying to do it right (in my eyes; this is my first real WP8 App), I changed all my Templates from ControlTemplates to DataTemplates and updated my `MyConverter` to return DataTemplate objects based on the `ChildViewModelProperty` bound to the `ItemTemplate`:

```
public class MyConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Converter(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        MyEnumType enumType = MyEnumType.DefaultType;
        Enum.TryParse<MyEnumType>(value.ToString(), out enumType);

        DataTemplate template = null;

        switch (enumType)
        {
            case MyEnumType.Type1:
                template = (DataTemplate)App.Current.Resources["MyEmumTypeTemplate1"];
                break;
            case MyEnumType.Type2:
                template = (DataTemplate)App.Current.Resources["MyEnumTypeTemplate2"];
                break;
            default:
                template = (DataTemplate)App.Current.Resources["MyEnumTypeTemplateDefault"];
                break;
        }

        return template;
    }

    ...
}
```

Then I updated my LongListSelector to bind the `ItemTemplate` directly to my `ChildViewModelProperty` of type `MyEnumType` with my `MyConverter` (declared in App.xaml as a static resource) converter as so:

```
<phone:LongListSelector x:Name="MyLongListSelector"
                        IsGroupingEnabled="False"
                        ItemsSource="{Binding ChildViewModels}"
                        ItemTemplate="{Binding MyEnumType, Converter={StaticResource MyConverter}}"
</phone:LongListSelector>
```

Now, when I view my app in the designer or in the emulator, my LongListSelector outputs a list with all of my elements presented as their `.ToString()` value (i.e. their fully qualified name).

What I've found is that `ParentViewModel` is being passed into `MyConverter` instead of each of the `ChildViewModel.MyEnumType` values. When I take out the specified Binding PropertyName (`MyEnumProperty`) and step through the debugger, `value` is of type `ParentViewModel`, the inherited DataContext of the LongListSelector. When I enter my desired Property name for the Binding, it simply fails the binding and doesn't even get into the Converter.

I saw a previous article that mentioned something about the LLS not handling a template change, but it had a comment (in 2011) that it's been fixed. I figured since it's 2013, it shouldn't be an issue anymore.

Am I missing something obvious, or do I need a go a little bit further? Or did I do it right in the first place with the Button?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that when your binding is evaluated in the context of the LongListSelector as a whole and at that time the data context is the `ChildViewModels`. It is not reevaluated when implementing the individual item.

The approach I'd take to address your problem would be to implement a custom DataTemplateSelector that can choose the datatemplate based on the enum value.

```
<phone:LongListSelector x:Name="MyLongListSelector"
                        IsGroupingEnabled="False"
                        ItemsSource="{Binding ChildViewModels}">
    <phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <MyDataTemplateSelector Content="{Binding}">
                <MyDataTemplateSelector.Type1>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        // ... your content here
                    </DataTemplate>
                </MyDataTemplateSelector.Type1>
                <MyDataTemplateSelector.Type2>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        // ... your content here
                    </DataTemplate>
                </MyDataTemplateSelector.Type2>
                <MyDataTemplateSelector.Default>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        // ... your content here
                    </DataTemplate>
                </MyDataTemplateSelector.Default>
            </MyDataTemplateSelector>
        </DataTemplate>
    </phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
</phone:LongListSelector>
```

There's an example of how to implement such a selector at http://www.geekchamp.com/articles/implementing-windows-phone-7-datatemplateselector-and-customdatatemplateselector